# SDR software support for National Instruments USB-4431 ADC?

Tags: software-defined-radio, equipment

I have an opportunity to purchase one or more of these [24 bit, 4 channel, 102ksps USB ADCs](http://sine.ni.com/nips/cds/view/p/lang/en/nid/206676), but before I do I want to understand how difficult they would be to use with existing SDR software.

Are there any windows SDR software packages known to connect to National Instruments input devices without extra work?

If not, is there SDR software that has an API or similar so one can easily add their own analog input drivers to attach the SDR software to custom or unsupported hardware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at [GNU Radio](http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki), it has a large following and is open source.

They already have an extensive list of hardware support.
http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/Hardware

Comment: I don't see the hardware in question on that list. I thought maybe it would, through the Comedi interface, but I [don't see it there, either](http://www.comedi.org/hardware.html).

Comment: @PhilFrost downvoting me? Did it occur to you that I was answering the other part of his question?

"If not, is there SDR software that has an API or similar so one can easily add their own analog input drivers to attach the SDR software to custom or unsupported hardware?"

Comment: It did occur to me, but besides that this doesn't directly answer the question (you don't even say GNU Radio *doesn't* support the USB-4431), the answer is little more than a link, which qualifies as *not useful* to me. *Why* is GNU Radio better than any other SDR library? Can you link to any of the documentation? Can you link to the API for the USB-4431 and summarize how they might fit together to implement the goal? I like GNU Radio too, but you don't say much relevant to the question about it.

Comment: @PhilFrost All the documentation happens to be readily accessible on that link, after all it is the "WIKI". There is a whole section on development on that very page. http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki#IV-Developing-GNU-Radio

Comment: That's all fine and good, but it doesn't [make your question any more useful](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). You should, at a minimum, say that GNU Radio does not support the hardware in question. Then you should expand your answer to include some value *beyond* what anyone can already get from Google.